# Script tag not working in html document

Tags: jquery, html

So when I put in a script tag into my html document, the script tag lights up, but when I put in the jquery stuff inside, it doesn't light up like it usually would. Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: You need to put some details friend..

Comment: http://imgur.com/jSVahB6 Here is an image to it, I thought I put one on

Comment: Do you mean `<scipt>` or `<script>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to correct spelling of your `<script></script>` tag

Then i think `panel` would be your `class` or `id`so you need to mention it as

```
$('.panel').hide().slideDown(1000);
```

or as

```
$('#panel').hide().slideDown(1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems

1. Its `script` tag not `scipt`
2. [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is a function
3. Its [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) not `slidedown()`
4. Document-ready handler function is not closed properly.

Code

```
<script> //Spelling of script is incorrect.
$(function(){
    $('panel').hide().slideDown(1000);
}); //Also have error in this line
</script>
```

Comment: I have changed it, but it just shows up like this: http://imgur.com/rnbusEV

Answer (score 1):

Your last block has a typo in it: it hast to be `<script>` not `<scipt>`